# 初期設定スクリプト

Tags: softlayer

SoftLayerでサーバーを展開する時、初期設定スクリプトを登録する事ができますか

Answer (score 1):

provisioning script で設定できます。こちらが参考になります。
http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/zembutsu/soft-layer-lt1-provisoning-script